# How do I implement a sticky header for an HTML table in IE11?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a table using HTML, Bootstrap, CSS and JS (and jQuery) for a client who is still using Internet Explorer 11. I cannot find a way to make its header sticky in IE.

I am currently using `position: sticky;`, which is working in all the three major browsers (Edge, Chrome & Firefox). I am aware it's not supported in IE. Below is a picture of my table. It has headers within headers using `rowspan`.
I have tried different polyfills and solutions but they either break something or just don't work.

[image: the table itself]

Here is the HTML and CSS I am using for the table.

```css
tr>th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tr1>th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px #212529;
}

.tr2>th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 93px;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px #212529;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

tr>td {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.add-btn {
  font-size: 11px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* background-color: red; */
}

.no-padding td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.no-padding td input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer" style="overflow-x:auto; height: 600px">
    <table id="clockings-table" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="tr1">
          <th rowspan="2" class="locked">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy" colspan="2">dummy1 <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button></th>
          <th class="dummy" colspan="5">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy" colspan="5">dummy1 <button id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="dummy" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button></th>

          <th class="dummy" colspan="5">dummy1 <button id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="dummy" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button></th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr2">
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>

          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>

          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>

          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this? Should I try scripting it in JavaScript? Is it a simple HTML/CSS trick that I've missed? It would be great to see your ideas.

Comment: Google/Yahoo/Bing/DuckDuckGo/... -> _"ie11 sticky header site:stackoverflow.com"_

Comment: IE doesn't support sticky, you have to use a javascript solution in IE for this problem.

Comment: You want to have a fixed header position vertically or horizontally?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no *simple* HTML+CSS solution that will work for IE11 without fixed column widths. (`position: fixed` solutions will work with fixed column widths). So you'll need to find a solution from before `position: sticky` or that says it supposed IE11 in [this search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+stick+table+header) or similar. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: If you want a fixed header position of your headers vertically. just make a fixed `max-height` of your `tbody` so you'll have a sticky behavior.

Comment: @Techuila I am not sure I understand what you mean. I want the header to stay in place when scrolling the table.

Answer (score 0):

So you wanted your header to stay in place when scrolling the table.

Why not make a fixed `max-height` of the `tbody` of your table and add `overflow-y: auto`?

Here's an example:

```js
// Ignore this, this is just to fill the table with dummy data for the purspose of making an example

$(document).ready(() => {
  const dummy_data = new Array(10).fill(null).map(e => `<tr><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td><td>dummy</td></tr>`);
  
  $('#clockings-table tbody').append(dummy_data)
})
```

```css
tr>th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}


tr>td {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.add-btn {
  font-size: 11px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* background-color: red; */
}

/* Table css */
table tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: overlay;
}

table tbody tr{
  width: 100%;
}

thead, tbody tr {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <table id="clockings-table" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="tr1">
          <th rowspan="2" class="locked">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy" colspan="2">dummy1 <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button></th>
          <th class="dummy" colspan="5">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy" colspan="5">dummy1 <button id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="dummy" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button></th>

          <th class="dummy" colspan="5">dummy1 <button id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="dummy" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button></th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
          <th rowspan="2">dummy1</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr2">
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>

          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>

          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>

          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
          <th class="dummy">dummy1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I never ended up fixing this and I took a different approach altogether. Thanks just the same.